# Order set of 4 character long words in decreasing order

Tags: arrays, string, sorting, vector, radix-sort

I am currently studying algorithms and data structures and preparing for my next exam, this is a problem I have found and I am not entirely sure if my solution is correct:
Given a set of 4-letter words such that each letter belongs to the English alphabet {A, ..., X, Y, Z}, order the set in decreasing order with respect to the lexicographic ordering.

My solution and doubts:

To solve this problem I think the best sorting algorithm would be a radix sort with complexity O(4(k + n)) so this is solved in linear time the algorithm should be something like this:

```
radixsort(array a, int d)
    b = []
    for int i = 1 to d
        countingsort(a, b, d, 26)
```

Is this the right way to solve the problem?

Comment: If you know how to write `countingsort` to sort in increasing order, can you rewrite it and reverse the inequalities so that it sorts in decreasing order? What is the difficulty you are facing exactly?

Comment: @Stef yes thank you, i have changed my question now.